# Partitioning tables in Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning

I had 160GB hdd with around 90GB of data and wanted to install Linux Mint on it (no other OS installed). It required ext filesystem, but hdd was ntfs. So I pressed "Add new partition table" and somehow managed to make him install Linux and create ext without formatting hdd (the Format box wasn't checked), and made a swap area from Free space. When I logged on to Linux, I couldn't see my files cause they weren't in Linux Filesystem, and I couldn't enter hdd through My Computer cause it says "Unable to mount this drive".
My question is: did I format all hdd and lost data or they are somewhere on hdd (if yes, how can I mount it).
Sorry if it's dumb question, but I never fully understood partitioning and was always afraid of it (losing the data).

Comment: Hello Bade, please could you do a `sudo fdisk -l` from Mint and [edit] and add the response to your question?

Comment: If you created a new partition table, you've destroyed your existing data. It's worth using `fdisk` to verify that this is what happened, though.

Comment: Well, the data (at least the portion of it that hasn't been overwritten) is still there, just inaccessible. Some of it might potentially be recoverable...